# Can send emails with SES account but not receive with the same email on GoDaddy

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I am running a website on an EC2 instance I created for testing. The page runs fine but I came across a big problem: One of the main functions of the website is to send emails multiple times to our providers. For testing purposes I told the site to send it to me in various different emails.

I sent it to my GMail and GoDaddy accounts, I have only received the GMail email.

The GoDaddy accounts have been added to the SES emails lists so we can have a bigger number of emails to send. Is this the reason I can't receive those emails?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: probably went into spam.  Also godaddy will refuse if the sender email address and IP are not linked in the `txt srv` record properly

Comment: Hello @Forbs, thank you for your comment. I previously linked the txt record on GoDaddy and it was verified.